# Using web workers with chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, web-worker

What I am trying to achieve here, is to execute a `XHRHttpRequest()` on a worker to speedup my extension. I am using `worker_proxy.js` from [here](https://github.com/Rob--W/chrome-api/tree/master/worker_proxy). It is working totally fine except that I am unable figure out how to pass a string to this worker.
Here is my code:

**manifest.json**

```json
{
  "permissions": [
     "alarms",
     "activeTab",
     "tabs",
     "webNavigation",
     "http://*/*", 
     "https://*/*",
     "cookies"
  ],  
  "options_page": "options.html",
  "background": {
    "persistent": false,
    "scripts": [ "worker_proxy.js","background.js"]
  },
  "content_scripts": [
     {
        "matches": ["https://*/*","http://*/*"],
        "js": ["jquery-2.1.4.js","hmac-sha256.js","enc-base64-min.js","worker_proxy.js","content.js"]
     }
  ],
  "web_accessible_resources": [ "worker_proxy.html","worker.js"],
}
```

**worker.js**

```js
var somestring=getStringFromContentJS()
    
var xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();
var request="GETgoogle.com"
xhr.open("GET", request, false);
xhr.send(someString);
    
postMessage('Result\n' + xhr.responseText);
```

**content.js**

```js
var az_worker = new Worker(chrome.runtime.getURL('getAzProducts.js'));

az_worker.onmessage = function(event) {
   alert('Message from worker: ' + event.data);
};
```

I am able to receive the data from `worker.js`, but how do I send data to it .i.e.,

`var somestring=getStringFromContentJS()`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To send data to a worker, simply add the following to the top of worker.js:

```
self.onmessage = function(event) {
    // Do something with event.data
};
```

and use `az_worker.postMessage(somestring);` to send data to it.

---

But your code is unnecessarily complex. If your goal is "to speedup my extension", then you should **not** be using Web workers to make synchronous XHR, but use **asynchronous XHR** on the main thread. Web Workers are great for CPU-bound tasks, but don't provide any advantage for I/O tasks such as network requests.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest for tutorials on using XMLHttpRequest.