# using WebAssembly in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, web-worker, webassembly

I have a chrome extension that includes a complicated function `comp_func(data)` which takes a lot of CPU by performing many bitwise operations. Because of that, I'm trying to use WebAssembly.

I've tried to follow several tutorials, for example [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebAssembly/Using_the_JavaScript_API) one and [this](https://tutorialzine.com/2017/06/getting-started-with-web-assembly) one.

The first link says:

```
fetch('simple.wasm').then(response =>
  response.arrayBuffer()
).then(bytes =>
  WebAssembly.instantiate(bytes, importObject)
).then(results => {
  results.instance.exports.exported_func();
});
```

but I get an error:

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: WebAssembly Instantiation: Import #0 module="env" error: module is not an object or function

I've tried a lot to use this approach, but it didn't work. I can't understand how to use WebAssembly that is loaded from the `.wasm` file.

So I've tried an easier approach:
The second link says to put this line in the html file:

```
<script src="index.js"></script>
```

and then just use the exported function:

```
var result = _roll_dice();
```

BUT, I'm in an extension so I only have a `background.html` file.
So I'm looking for a way to access the Module which was loaded in the background file.
And things get complicated, **because the function `comp_func(data)` is called from a [Worker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32853359/using-web-workers-with-chrome-extension).**

This is what I've tried so far:

If I call `chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage()` I can access the Module
but I can't send it to the Worker:

> Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'Worker': # could not be cloned.

And if I try to `stringify` it first:

> Uncaught TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON

(I tried to un-circular it, didn't work...)

And I can't call `chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage()` from the Worker because I can't access chrome API from there.

**So my questions are**:

1. Did someone try to load `.wasm` file in chrome extension and succeed?
   The second approach (loading the `js` file) sounds simpler but if you have a working example for this approach it would be great.

or 2. How to access the Module that has been loaded in `background.html` (from the second example)?

or 3. How to pass the functions that I needed from the js file to the Worker (via `postMessage`)?

*To summarize, did someone try to use WebAssembly in a chrome extension and survive to tell?*

**EDIT**:
I eventually left the approach of WebAssembly.
I also posted this question at [bugs-chromium](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=828012#c2),
and after few month got an answer. Not sure if this is really working, but maybe this, along with the marked answer, will help someone.

Comment: I think it's possible extensions can't run wasm yet. As for the messaging part: 1) only simple data can be transferred using chrome API i.e. numbers, strings, booleans, arrays and objects that consist of such simple data, 2) Workers can also transfer [a few specific types](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Transferable), 3) functions aren't transferable.

Comment: Do you have any idea how I can check for sure if extensions can't run wasm?

Comment: You can ask on https://crbug.com and/or [Chromium-Extensions-Announce](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/d/forum/chromium-extensions).

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I've been fiddling with WebAssembly recently, and found a way to make it work. Here are the script files:

**main.js**

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
 chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file: "content_script.js"});
});
```

**content_script.js**

```
  var importObject = { imports: { imported_func: arg => console.log(arg) } };
  url = 'data:application/wasm;base64,' + "AGFzbQEAAAABCAJgAX8AYAAAAhkBB2ltcG9ydHMNaW1wb3J0ZWRfZnVuYwAAAwIBAQcRAQ1leHBvcnRlZF9mdW5jAAEKCAEGAEEqEAAL";
  WebAssembly.instantiateStreaming(fetch(url), importObject)
  .then(obj => obj.instance.exports.exported_func());
```

The data URL belongs to the common tutorial wasm sample (simple.wasm), which writes 42 on the console.

---

PS. If it seems like cheating or bad practice to you, this content_script.js also works:

```
var importObject = {
   imports: {
    imported_func: function(arg) {
    console.log(arg);
    }
   }
 };

var response = null;
var bytes = null;
var results = null;


var wasmPath = chrome.runtime.getURL("simple.wasm");
fetch(wasmPath).then(response =>
    response.arrayBuffer()
    ).then(bytes =>
       WebAssembly.instantiate(bytes, importObject)
        ).then(results => {
        results.instance.exports.exported_func();
  });
```

Only if you include the code files in the **web_accessible_resources** section in manifest.json, though:

```
    ...
    "web_accessible_resources": [
     "content_script.js",
     "main.js",
     "simple.wasm"
    ],
    ...
```

Github: https://github.com/inflatablegrade/Extension-with-WASM

It can also be [made compatible](https://github.com/inflatablegrade/Extension-with-WASM/tree/manifest-v3) with [Manifest V3](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/intro/).

Comment: When you use WASM, does the Chrome app store require the source code for code review before publishing?

Comment: To be honest, I never tried it. I just wanted to see if it's doable as a concept. My extension doesn't serve any practical purpose, so I didn't attempt to publish it. WASM has a lot of potential for computing-intensive web apps and extensions, but I don't have a particular extension idea for that. It's compatible with Manifest V3 though.

Comment: Actually, uBlock Origin has WASM in it: https://github.com/gorhill/uBlock/tree/master/src/js/wasm

Comment: Nice! Could you pls share what C code and compile command you used to create simple.wasm?